# How to configure Visual Studio Code to build a project with IAR compiler?

Tags: visual-studio-code, iar

I want to use **Visual Studio Code** as my main IDE, but I want to compile my code with IAR's compiler.

How could I configure VSCode ?

I found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=politoleo.iar#overview) but the documentation is too poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the extension [politoleo.iar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=politoleo.iar#overview) is indeed NOT good.

-> I found a better one (will try it in future by myself):

- VSCode plugin: `pluyckx.iar-vsc`

  - [IAR For Visual Studio Code - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pluyckx.iar-vsc)

    - [image: iar vsc plugin]
- **Good** document

  - [Welcome to IAR-VSC’s documentation! — IAR-VSC 1.2 documentation](https://iar-vsc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

    - doc's Github source: [pluyckx/iar-vsc](https://github.com/pluyckx/iar-vsc/)
- IAR related official `Technical Note`

  - [Using Visual Studio Code with IAR Embedded Workbench](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/using-visual-studio-code-with-iar-embedded-workbench/)

Enjoy it !

Answer (score 5):

There are now two official IAR plugins for VSCode which make things much easier:

- For building and development: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iarsystems.iar-build
- For debugging with C-Spy: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iarsystems.iar-debug

https://www.iar.com/knowledge/support/technical-notes/general/using-visual-studio-code-with-iar-embedded-workbench/

Comment: There's also a video here https://www.iar.com/vscode

Answer (score 0):

What I did is setting some environment variables in settings.json;
then in tasks.json I created shell tasks that call the IarBuild.exe & IarIdePm.exe with appropriate values (see the documentation on  the command line options)...

So now, I can use VSCode for navigation & editing, but the compilation is done by the EWARM.

The only thing that I haven't figure out yet is how to make C-Spy work from within VSCode...

Currently when I want to debug, I just launch the EWARM and debug from there...

here is a screenshot:[Screenshot of settings.json and tasks.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjlrX.png)

Comment: Is there an update to the C-Spy problem ? I am currently stuck there too.

Comment: Nope... There is a technical note on IAR's web site regarding the VSCode. There they mentioned that currently there is no support for C-Spy.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can port you project to the custom build system (non iarbuild), e.g. a best choose is the [Qbs](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/index.html). The Qbs support a lot of architectures and the toolchains (include IAR, KEIL and so on). In this case you can then use any IDE which support the Qbs, e.g. such as VSCode or QtCreator, and to open your project in any of these IDEs.

Both IDEs support only the GDB debugging, because the C-Spy debuger is a proptietary technology, which has not the public datasheets.